# Why is -compile(export_all) bad practice?

Tags: erlang

All the erlang books seem to say export_all is bad practice but don't give a reason. In the end most modules spend a majority of their time with compile(export_all) because constantly updating the list of modules to remove the helper functions is a hassle. Is it bad practice because I'm supposed to care about the functions I expose to other developers? Or is it bad practice because there's some kind of performance cost in the number of functions a module has, because of maybe things like hot code loading. If there is a performance hit to stuffing a module with a lot of functions, how bad is it?

Comment: because it is easier to reverse engineer and unnecessarily produce larger executable than needed. no one needs your function names in executable right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For several reasons:

- Clarity: it's easier to see which functions are intended to be used outside the module.

  When you tab complete in the Erlang shell you get a list of only the exported functions and no others. When you refactor the module, you know which functions you can safely rename without external users depending on them.
- Code smell: you get warnings for unused functions.

  Therefore you'll avoid dead code.
- Optimization: the compiler might be able to make more aggressive optimizations knowing that not all functions have to be exported.

Comment: Do you have a source to back up the optimization claim?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I'd imagine it would be able to inline functions used only in one place for example, if it knows they'll never be called from outside the module.

Comment: In addition, it makes the dialyzer harder to use. @jocull In Joe Armstrong's book, Programming Erlang, 2nd ed., pg. 164, he states that the "compiler can produce much better code" when you export less functions.

Answer (score 10):

While I don't know for sure if there are any practical performance implications of using `-compile(export_all).`, I doubt they are significant enough to care.

However, there a benefit of declaring the list of exports explicitly. By doing this, everyone can figure out the interface of the module by looking at the first page of the `.erl` file. Also, as with many other things that we tend to write down, explicit declaration of the module interface helps to maintain its clarity.

With that said, when I start working on a new Erlang module I always type `-module(...). -compile(export_all).` After the interface becomes mature enough I add an explicit `-export([...])` *while keeping* the `export_all` compile option.

Comment: There are no performance implications of using `-compile(export_all).`. The compiler handles all calls the same and the exporting is done the same way as with explicit export.

Answer (score 3):

Having a defined list of which functions are external, and therefore which ones are internal, is extremely useful for anyone who will work on your code in the future. I've recently been refactoring some old code, and the use of export_all in most of the modules has been a continual source of annoyance.