# Concurrency in Erlang and its proper workflow

Tags: concurrency, erlang

this code was given to us by our teacher but sadly, was not explained. We just tried this in the class and then was dismissed.

it would be very helpful if someone could thoroughly explain this code to me. thanks in advance.

```
-module(pingpong).
-compile(export_all).

start_pong() ->
    register(pong, spawn(pingpong,pong,[])).

pong() ->
    receive
        finished ->
            io:format("Pong finished ~n");
        {ping, Ping_Pid} ->
            io:format("i am the receiver ~n"),
        Ping_Pid ! pong,
        pong()
end.

start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    spawn(pingpong, ping, [3, Pong_Node]).

ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished,
    io:format("Pong finished ~n");

ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()},
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("i am the sender ~n")
    end,
    ping(N-1,Pong_Node).
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's have a look at the first two lines.

```
-module(pingpong).
-compile(export_all).
```

The first is the module declaration, where its argument is an *atom* (or, in other words, a lowercase word, without quotes). Taken from *Learn You Some Erlang*:

> **`-module(Name).`**
>   This is always the first attribute (and statement) of a file, and for good reason: it's the name of the current module, where Name is an atom. This is the name you'll use to call functions from other modules. The calls are made with the **`M:F(A)`** form, where **`M`** is the module name, **`F`** the function, and **`A`** the arguments.

The second sentence tells your compiler to make all declared functions *public*, *ie*, every function `F` you write on that module will be able to be called by outsiders as `pingpong:F`.
This may simplify the process when you're first learning, but it usually is a bad practice. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863087/why-is-compileexport-all-bad-practice).

---

Let's have a look at the functions now.

```
start_pong() ->
    register(pong, spawn(pingpong,pong,[])).
```

This is probably where your code will start. You compile the module, and then call `pingpong:start_pong().` in the Erlang shell of a given machine, or node. All this function does is *"register the name **pong** as the identifier for the process I'm about to create, with `spawn`"*.

So, `spawn` creates an Erlang process. `spawn` is also a built-in function (BIF), and thus does not require that you prepend its module name. Its arguments are `spawn(Module, Exported_Function, List of Arguments)`, as seen [in the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html).
Looking back at `start_pong`, all it does is *"create a process that will start by running the `pong` function in this module, with no arguments, and call that process **pong**"*.

---

```
pong() ->
    receive
        finished ->
            io:format("Pong finished ~n");
        {ping, Ping_Pid} ->
            io:format("i am the receiver ~n"),
        Ping_Pid ! pong,
        pong()
end.
```

The newly created process in `start_pong` will run this function. Every process in Erlang has its own *mailbox*. Processes communicate with each other by leaving messages in those mailboxes. Messages may be *almost* anything. Think of them as some data that you like to send between processes.

The fresh process enters the `receive` statement, which tells it to fetch a message from its mailbox, or to wait until there's some. Then it uses **pattern matching** to find the appropriate action, when a message is received. If you're used to imperative languages, think of this as a `switch`, otherwise ignore this statement.

If the process has a message with the single atom `finished`, it prints `Pong finished` in the console and exits.
If the process has a message that is a pair with the atom `ping` and a **process identifier** (*pid* - every process has one), then it will execute the remaining code of the function.

The uppercase `Ping_Pid` tells Erlang to assign whatever second value the message has to the variable with the name `Ping_Pid`. It just so happens that you expect a *pid*.
What it does, when entering this case, is printing `i am the receiver`, then sends a message with the atom `pong` to the process identified by `Ping_Pid` - that's what the `!` operator is for. Finnaly, the function calls itself, in order to go look at the mailbox again.

---

The next thing you'll write on the console, probably on another node/machine, will be the call to `start_ping`.

```
start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    spawn(pingpong, ping, [3, Pong_Node]).
```

As we've seen before, all this does is creating a process that will run the `ping` function, with arguments `3` and the `Pong_Node` it receives, which is the machine (node) where the first process is running.

---

```
ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished,
    io:format("Pong finished ~n");

ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()},
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("i am the sender ~n")
    end,
    ping(N-1,Pong_Node).
```

This function is defined in two cases (note that the first `ping` block ends with `;`, rather than `.` - this tells Erlang that there's more to define the function).

You call it with `3` as the first argument. Since `3` does not match with `0`, the process executes the second case, with `N` as its argument.

This process sends the pair `{ping, self()}` to the process given by `{pong, Pong_Node}`, which follows the syntax `{registered_name, node_name}`. `self()` is used to retrieve the current process's own *pid*.
After this, the process waits for the `pong` response, and repeats this again, while `N` is bigger than zero.

When `N` reaches zero, the first case is executed, sending `finished` to `{pong, Pong_Node}`, and ending execution.

---

If you feel this explanation is incomplete, you may also have a look [at the tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#id67009), which depicts this exact program.

Comment: Nice answer which took some time to write down, I am sure!