# How to define functions without exporting them?

Tags: erlang

I am working through *Learn You Some Erlang*, and in the discussion on tail recursion, the author defines two functions: `tail_fac/1` and `tail_fac/2`. The book mentions that one would only export the `tail_fac/1`. How does one go about defining a function, in this case, `tail_fac/2`, without exporting it? The only way I know to define a function is `-export([func_name/args])`.

When I attempt to run the code snippet:

```
tail_fac(N) -> tail_fac(N,1).

tail_fac(0,Acc) -> Acc;
tail_fac(N,Acc) when N > 0 -> tail_fac(N-1,N*Acc).
```

My linter says that `tail_fac/2` is undefined, even if I try to define it in exports.

Comment: You should not put dot at the end of first function declaration. All function with the same name must be separated by semicolon. Erlang just thinks that there is only one function with the name "tail_fac".

Comment: @Alex Not quite true, function clauses should be separated with semicolon if they have the same name and the same arity, but functions with same name and different arities should be separated by dots. So this code looks perfectly fine to me. I compiled this code and tested out tail_fac/1 and it seems to work perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: Ok, then I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Erlang actually you can use always use `-compile(export_all)`, which will export *all* of your functions, but [it's not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863087/why-is-compileexport-all-bad-practice).

It's just a matter of point of view- in Ruby, Python or Elixir you have to explicitly tell what methods/functions you want to keep private. In Erlang you just do the same, but with public functions.

Generally: you export functions with lower number of arguments, which is actually a wrapper for function, which uses more arguments (accumulators etc.).

For example:

```
sum(N) -> sum(N, 0).
sum(0, Acc) -> Acc;
sum(N, Acc) -> sum(N - 1, Acc + N).
```

And if you export only `sum/1` it's completely fine. You don't want to bother your end user with `sum/2`.

Comment: But how would you define sum/2, if not in exports?

Comment: I don't export it, but it's defined in the file. `sum/1` can use `sum/2` internally on file level. Definition is something different than exporting.